# Function context ("this") in nested functions

Tags: javascript

When you invoke a top-level function in Javascript, the *this* keyword inside the function refers to the default object (window if in a browser). My understanding is that it's a special case of invoking the function as method, because by default it is invoked on window (as explained in John Resig's book, Secrets of the JavaScript Ninja, page 49). And indeed both invocations in the following code are identical.

```
function func() {
  return this;
}

// invoke as a top-level function
console.log(func() === window); // true

// invoke as a method of window
console.log(window.func() === window); // true
```

So far so good... Now here is the part I don't understand:

When a function is nested in another function and invoked without specifying an object to invoke on, the *this* keyword inside the function also refers to window. But the inner function cannot be invoked on window (see code below).

```
function outerFunc() {
  function innerFunc() {
    return this;
  }

  // invoke without window.* - OK
  console.log(innerFunc() === window); // true

  // invoke on window
  //window.innerFunc(); - error (window has no such method)
  console.log(window.innerFunc) // undefined
}

outerFunc();
```

It makes perfect sense that the nested function isn't available on window, as it is after all nested... But then I don't understand why the this keyword refers to window, as if the function was invoked on window. What am I missing here?

**EDIT**

Here is a summary of the great answers below and some of my follow up research.

- It is incorrect to say that invoking a function "normally" is the same as invoking it as a method of *window*. This is only correct if the function is defined globally.
- The function context (the value of the *this* keyword) does not depend on where / how the function is defined, but on how it is being invoked.
- Assuming that the code is not running in in strict mode, Invoking a function "normally" will have the function context set to to window (when running in a browser, or the corresponding global object in other environments).
- An exception to the above rules is the use of *bind* to create a function. In this case even if the function is invoked "normally", it could have a context other than *window*. That is, in this case the context is determined by how you create the function, rather than how you invoke it. Although strictly speaking this isn't accurate, because *bind* creates a new function that internally invokes the given function using *apply*. The context of that new function will still be determined by the way it's invoked, but it shields the context of the function it internally invokes by using *apply*.

By invoking "normally" I refer to the following simple way of invocation:

`myFunction();`

To complete the picture, here is a brief coverage of other ways of invocation and the corresponding context:

- As a property of an object (method) - the context is the object
- Using apply or call - the context is specified explicitly
- With the *new* operator (as a constructor) - the context is a newly created object

Feel free to update the above as necessary, for the benefit of people with similar questions. Thanks!

Comment: The explanation is ok, but it's only an approximation. Whenever a function is invoked "normally", `this` refers to the global object (`window`), unless the function is in strict mode. That's just how it is. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call any function that is in scope with `functionName()`. Since you haven't called it on an object, it will be called in the context of the default object (`window`). (IIRC, it will be called in the context of `undefined` if you are in strict mode).

The default object for context has nothing to do with where a function is defined or what scope that function appears in. It is simply the default object.

If a function is a property of an object, you can call it as `reference.to.object.function()`, and it will be called in the context of `object` instead of the default object.

Other things that change the context are the `new` keyword and the `apply`, `call`, and `bind` methods.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, when a function is invoked without an explicit context, the context is the global object. In the case of web browsers, the global object is `window`.

Additionally, JavaScript has functional scope, so any variables or functions within a function are not accessible in a scope outside of that function. This is why you can't access `window.innerFunc`.

Answer (score 0):

Whether a function is nested inside another one has nothing to do with the value of `this` when the function is called. The only things that matter are:

- If the function is "found" by traversing a property on an object, then the value of `this` will be a reference to that object:

  ```
  someObject.prop( whatever );
  ```

  It doesn't matter how the function was declared.
- If you use `call()` or `apply()` to invoke a function, then the value of `this` is taken from the first argument to whichever of those functions you use.
- If you've created a bound wrapper for the function with `bind()`, then the value of `this` will be as requested when `bind()` was called.
- If you're calling a function as a constructor with `new`, then `this` will refer to the newly-created object instance.
- Otherwise, `this` is either a reference to the global context, or else it's `undefined` (in "strict" mode or in an ES5-compliant runtime).

The "location" in the code where a function is defined does matter, of course, in that the scope includes whatever symbols it includes, and those are available to the function regardless of how a reference to it is obtained.

Answer (score 0):

It does not depend where the function is declared but how it is called:

```
var obj = {
   f: function() {
       return this;
   }
}

var f = obj.f;

console.log(obj.f()) // obj
console.log(f()) // window/default obj
```

Or in other words. The syntax `obj.f()` executes the function with `this=obj` while `f()` executes the function with `this=window`. In JavaScript the caller specifies the value of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `func` in the global scope, it actually is assigned as a property of the `window` object. That is, the `window` object holds all globally scoped variables. (*) Therefore, `func` and `window.func` represent the same thing. `innerFunc` is defined inside a function scope and is not available outside of that scope. Therefore, `window.innerFunc` is (still) `undefined`.

However, the `this` context is determined by how you *call* the function. When you call a method like `obj.method()`, the `this` context is set to `obj`. On the other hand, you can also call the method on its own:

```
var f = obj.func;
f(); // in this call: this === window
```

In this case, you're not calling a function on an object and thus the `this` context is set to the default. The default however is the *global scope* and as stated above, this is represented by `window`.

You can always override the `this` context by using `Function.prototype.call()` or `Function.prototype.apply()` which take a `this` context as first argument. For example:

```
var f = obj.func;
f.call(obj); // in this call: this == obj
```

(*) Note that this only applies to JavaScript running inside a browser. In other environments, this may differ. For example, in Node.js the `GLOBAL` variable holds the global scope.