# jQuery: How to call a function via string within a class

Tags: jquery, scope

How to call a function via string within a class?

```
$.fn.myApp = function (options){
  function myFunc(){
    //do something
  }
  window["myFunc"](); //not working
  $.fn.myApp["myFunc"](); //not working
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to call it via a string?

Comment: You may have simply omitted this in the question, but you do need `()` to execute the function, ex. `window['alert']('hi');`.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you describe it a bit.

Comment: I think this question isn't so much about the bracket notation, but the context of functions nested in other functions. [This SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14677627/function-context-this-in-nested-functions) may be of help.

Comment: @Jason P: No, this syntax is not working in my case: TypeError: window.myFunc is not a function

Comment: @Palatiner: I need to read and trigger functions from the attributes of links. example: <button data-ajax="true" data-func="myFunc">do it</button>

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, maybe that helps anybody else as well!

```
$.fn.myApp = function (options){
  $.fn.myApp.myFunc = function(){
    //do something
  }
  $.fn.myApp["myFunc"](); //working
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code: you need to expose the method in order to call it form outside that function: http://jsbin.com/aXuloFE/1/

Comment: I need to call the function within the class.